# SVN poll failed in custom workspace, reporting "Workspace appear to be locked"

Tags: jenkins

```
Building in workspace /data/www/wdqk/html/flash
Updating svn://192.168.1.200/wdqk/www/html/flash at revision '2013-09-17T15:15:15.460 +0800'
Workspace appear to be locked, so getting a fresh workspace
Cleaning local Directory .
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete /data/www/wdqk/html/flash/./.svn/entries
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:255)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:307)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:298)
    at hudson.Util.deleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:204)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:75)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:153)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:161)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:182)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:153)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:903)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:884)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:867)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:909)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:843)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:781)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1408)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1603)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Finished: FAILURE
```

This build is outside Jenkins's home directory.

I cannot find any lock file in the svn project folder.

Is it the permission issue?

Comment: Yes, it's most likely a permission issue. The "Workspace appear to be locked" is not the actual error by the way. It's just an information telling you that (and why) the workspace is cleaned and checked out again. The actual error happens while cleaning the workspace but not because it's locked.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel Thank you. Can you give me some advice as I don't want to manually execute `chown jenkins:jenkins` on my project folders.

Comment: I will put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's most likely a permission issue. As I see it, you have few ways to resolve it.

- Make your jenkins user the owner of the project folders. You already said in the comments that you don't want to do that.
- Set `chmod a+w` on your project folders. I would not recommend this as everybody would have write access to the folders. Could become as security issue.
- Create a new group, say `groupadd development`. Add your jenkins user and the owner of the project folders to that group (`usermod -a -G development jenkins` and `usermod -a -G development owneruser`). Now change the owner group of the project folders (`chown :development projectfolder`). Make sure the group has write access (`chmod g+w`) This one is a little bit of work but I think it's the best way.

The "Workspace appear to be locked" is not the actual error by the way. It's just an information telling you that (and why) the workspace is cleaned and checked out again. The actual error happens while cleaning the workspace but not because it's locked.